# How can I localize a resource in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, msbuild

I am learning about how to localize a project and using a book as a tutorial. I've added the `UICulture` to the `.csproj` and assembly files:

```
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en-US", UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.Satellite)]
```

But now the book says to update the elements with the UID and I don't know where to do it.

I have to invoke the `msbuild` (not sure form where) and need to use

```
msbuild/t:updateuid ProjectName.csproj.
```

How do I do this?

Comment: use the Visual Studio Command Prompt Tool, go to your project directory and run your MSBuild command..

Answer (score 0):

If I may suggest an alternative approach. I never liked the "default" Microsoft approach to localization in WPF, so way back in 2008 I started looking for alternatives.  I eventually settled on a solution described in an article named "Simple WPF Localization" on CodeProject. It's a XAML markup extension and it also allows you to change languages on the fly, etc.  Very simple to use.

The author now has a more capable, "advanced" version: [Advanced WPF Localization](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/249369/Advanced-WPF-Localization) that allows you to localize images, brushes, margins, etc. (it's all at the top of the article).

There are a few other such "libraries" available (some are on CodeProject as well), but I've been using this one for 3.5 years with no issues whatsoever.  Might be worth looking into if the approach fits what you're doing.